# Can not run Junit in eclipse

Tags: spring, junit

I am trying to run spring boot crud example with following code

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class CreateUserServiceTest {

```
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@InjectMocks
private CreateUserService createUserService;

@Test
public void whenSaveUser_shouldReturnUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Test Name");

    when(userRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);

    User created = createUserService.createNewUser(user);

    assertThat(created.getName()).isSameAs(user.getName());
    verify(userRepository).save(user);
}
```

}

But after run it gives bellow error.

"NO test found with test runner 'junit5'"

anyone please help me.

[Please check the error message from this file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6pIV.png)

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Comment: Looks like the test doesn't compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: I found the root cause.**

JUnit 5 uses annotations from a different package than JUnit 4. When you start a test, Eclipse automatically creates a launch configuration for JUnit 5, but if your annotations are not in the new package, Eclipse would not find the tests and will display the error message.

[New annotations](https://devqa.io/junit-5-annotations/):

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
// ... other imports from org.junit.jupiter.api
```

Old annotations:

```java
import org.junit.Test;
// ... imports without "jupiter" in their name
```

You need to add the following dependencies in a Maven project in order to use JUnit 5:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Workaround: Use JUnit 4.**
You need to select JUnit 4 in your launch configuration. Otherwise this error is shown.

From the main menu select Run -> Run configurations, then select your JUnit test configuration from the navigation bar on the left hand side.

[image]

Comment: after run according to your instruction . it can not work now

Comment: What happened? Did you get the error message again? In my IDE I have never been able to run tests when JUnit 5 is selected. Changing to JUnit 4 works for me.

Comment: yes thanks after selecting junit4  , it is working.

Comment: Nice! If you find the answer helpful, please vote. ;)

Comment: On the left hand side of the answer that helped there is a V sign that you can click and indicate the answer solved your problem.

Comment: i have another one problem for junit  when(userRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);  what is the purpose of this line ??

Comment: my total code is bellow 

        when(userRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);
        User created = createUserService.createNewUser(user);
        assertThat(created.getName()).isSameAs(user.getName());
        verify(userRepository).save(user);
    }

Comment: Please post it in a new question. Questions should not be mixed because afterwards people search and learn from them.

Comment: i can not create a new question due to following warning message.
You have reached your question limit

Comment: I don't know, you have to ask a moderator.

Comment: I found the root cause for the error. Please read the updated description.

Comment: what is the root cause ??

Comment: The JUnit 5 tests use annotations from a new namespace. The tests must be updated to work with JUnit 5.